# How to get latest videos from multiple Youtube channels in single API Call

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

Am using the below PHP code to get the latest videos from a user channel,

`$feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/USER-ID/uploads?max-results=50';
$sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);`

Is there any way I can call the Youtube API and get the videos from different user channels in the single API call. And list the videos in desc order on a page.

Comment: I noticed the answers below do not answer the question. Have you managed to find out how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, you werent very clear on your answer.

First of get the total videos uploaded by calling the api with a json format:

```
   http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/LinusTechTips/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc
```

use:

```
   $json = json_decode($jsonString); 
   print($json->data->totalItems . "\n");
```

to get the viewcount, then you can calculate the rest!

```
   $totalItems = $json->data->totalItems;
   $maxResults = 50
   $xmlResults = array();
   for($i = $maxResults > $totalItems-50; $i+$maxResults) {
          $xmlResults[] = simplexml_load_file(
             'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/LinusTechTips/uploads?max-results=' . $i
          );
   }
```

To be clear; this is not tested. So im not sure it works; but this is the way to do it.

**Note: XML is alot slower then json, I stronly advise you to use the json formatting!**

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set up a array with usernames/ids and foreach them. For example:

```
$usernames = array(
   'xeonnnnn',
   'LinusTechTips'
);

$xmlResults = null;
foreach ($usernames as $user) {
   $xmlResults[] = simplexml_load_file(
     'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/' . $user .'/uploads?max-results=50'
   );
}
```

Comment: but this will load the first 50 videos from first channels and so on, if you check my question, I want all the videos in desc order, like the most recent videos from all channels at the top and so on.