# youtube api to fetch id of the latest videos from multiple channels

Tags: php, youtube-api

Im trying to get the ids of the latest 3 videos from multiple channels in  order from new to old. this is the code im working with.

```
$latest_vid_id = NULL;
$username_id = array('djvlad', 'UCIMQYiLXCHQLZCfplSP1rMw','UCUsTSbCLD96-pcWi2Kqaitg');
foreach($username_id as $username) {
$xml = simplexml_load_file(sprintf('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/%s/uploads?alt=rss&v=2&orderby=published', $username));

if ( ! empty($xml->channel->item[0]->link) )
{
parse_str(parse_url($xml->channel->item[0]->link, PHP_URL_QUERY), $url_query);

if ( ! empty($url_query['v']) )
$latest_vid_id = $url_query['v'];
}

echo $latest_vid_id.'<br>';
}
```

the problem with this is it gets the ids of the latest video from each channel and i need the latest video out of all the channels. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<?php

$id = NULL;
$username = 'YouTube';

$xml = simplexml_load_file(sprintf('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/%s/uploads?alt=rss&v=2&orderby=published', $username));

if ( ! empty($xml->channel->item[0]->link) )
{
  parse_str(parse_url($xml->channel->item[0]->link, PHP_URL_QUERY), $url_query);

  if ( ! empty($url_query['v']) )
    $id = $url_query['v'];
}

echo $id;
```

Comment: thanks but this is only for one channel i want to get it from multiple channels.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789483/how-to-get-latest-videos-from-multiple-youtube-channels-in-single-api-call